# Cannot create an instance or abstract type or interface 'Button' XNA/Mono Game

Tags: c#, button, xna, monogame

Component.cs

```
public abstract class Component
    //abstract to it has to be inherited and any child will be
    //forced to use the Draw & Update class
    {
        public abstract void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch);

        public abstract void Update(GameTime gameTime);
    }
```

Button.cs

```
public abstract class Button : Component
    //abstract to it has to be inherited and any child will be
    //forced to use the Draw & Update class
    {
       // #region Fields

        private MouseState _currentMouse;
        private SpriteFont _font;

        private MouseState _previousMouse;
        private Texture2D _texture;
        // #endregion

        public event EventHandler Click;
        public Color TextColour { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
        public Rectangle Rectangle
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, _texture.Width, _texture.Height);
            }
        }
        public string Text { get; set; }


        public Button(Texture2D texture, SpriteFont font)
        {
            _texture = texture;

            _font = font;

            TextColour = Color.White;
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            var colour = Color.White;

            spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, Rectangle, colour);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {
                var x = (Rectangle.X + (Rectangle.Width / 2)) - (_font.MeasureString(Text).X / 2);
                var y = (Rectangle.Y + (Rectangle.Height / 2)) - (_font.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2);
                //center the font within the button

                spriteBatch.DrawString(_font, Text, new Vector2(x, y), TextColour);
            }
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            _previousMouse = _currentMouse;
            _currentMouse = Mouse.GetState();
            //sets position of the mouse to actual current position
            

            if (_currentMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released & _previousMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Click?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                //if click event handler is != null ....use it   
            }

        }
    }
```

I have these classes set up to register a button press on my game.

Within game1.cs I tried to add the following to load content.

```
 _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

var randomButton = new Button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Controls/Button"), Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/Font"))
{
               
};
```

When implementing this I get error code CS0144 "Cannot create an instance or abstract type or interface 'Button'"

at the top of game1 I am using namespace.Controls as Button.cs is located in a folder called Controls. Any assistance or advice on this would be welcomed.

Comment: You can't create an instance of an `abstract` class, your `Button` class is marked as `abstract` - [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) - "Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is intended only to be a base class of other classes, not instantiated on its own."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437161/c-sharp-cannot-create-an-instance-of-the-abstract-class-or-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is Button `abstract`?, abstract types cannot be initialized with the new keyword, instead their constructors are considered abstract and a derived type should call `base()` to it, consider not abstracting the class Button if possible (possible means: if you have any abstract member, than it is not possible, else, yes it is).

Comment: I went with abstract to force the child(Button) to use the draw and update class within Component. I gather this is not the correct approach to take

Comment: this is the abstraction for `Component`, not `Button`, therefore you can safely un abstract the `Button` class

Comment: I see my issue now, I accidentally made the button class its self abstract. I just needed to remove that. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome! Typos and accidents always happens with programmers, they are the bugs that happens with humanity :D